# JavaScript: enable textbox on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamic table generated by javascript from a dropdownlist selected item.
My table contains a column for checkbox,a column for displaying name and a column to input quantity.
All i want is to make all textboxs disabled untel its row get checked.
This is my javascript code and the disabled doesn't work for me.

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#ProduitID").change(function () {

            $.get("/Demandes/GetGabarit", { produit: $("#ProduitID").val() }, function (data) {

                $("#Gabarit").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {

                    $("#Gabarit").append($("<tr>").append("<td>" + "<input type=checkbox name= gabarit class=Check value='" + row.CodeBarre + "'/>" + "</td>"
                                                           + "<td>" + row.Designation + "</td>"
                                                        + "<td>" + "<input type=text style=width:50px; name=Qt  class=Quantite/>" + "</td>"

                   ));


                });
            })
        });

    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#checkBoxAll').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('.Check').prop('checked', true);
                $('.Quantite').prop('disabled', false);
}
            else{
                $('.Check').prop('checked', false);
                $('.Quantite').prop('disabled', true);
}
        });
    });

</script>
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produit, "Produit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CodeBarre, ViewBag.Produit as SelectList, "Sélectionner un produit", new { id = "ProduitID", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeBarre, "Gabarit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="25%"><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll" /></th>
                            <th width="25%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)</th>

                            <th width="25%">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantite)</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="Gabarit">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Designation"></td>

                            <td class="Quantite" ></td>
                            <td class="Check"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeBarre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please also post the HTML that goes with this JS? It is much more helpful to post a JSFiddle that it is NOT working than just a piece of code, that way we can fix the little issues you have instead of recreating the entire code for you. That way you will get a lot more responses for your question.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5  I edited my post and thank you

Comment: Thank you but that is not the rendered HTML, it is just a view. I posted a solution that might help you find the issue in your own code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkBoxAll', function() {

            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('.Check').prop('checked', true);
                $('.Quantite').prop('disabled', false);
}
            else{
                $('.Check').prop('checked', false);
                $('.Quantite').prop('disabled', true);
}

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't work with me :(

Comment: No errors but all the textboxes are enabled before checking

Comment: $(document).on('change', '.Check', function()  please try this

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your final HTML (you are posting a view) I can help you with this code:

```
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll" value="second_checkbox" checked="checked">


      <input type="textbox" id="txt1" class="Quantite" value="1"> 
      <input type="textbox" id="txt2" class="Quantite" value="2"> 
      <input type="textbox" id="txt3" class="Quantite" value="3">



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBoxAll').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('.Quantite').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
        else{
            $('.Quantite').prop('disabled','');
                    }
    });
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opmqnxfn/)

Comment: If you click the checkbox the textboxes are disabled (try entering some text and you will find that is not possible.) What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I want that before no checkbox is checked taht all textboxes are disabled after it will be checked the textBox become enabled.

Comment: And the View that i posted is where the javascript Code will be executed because the table is dynamic and appears on selecting an item from a dropdwonlist that's why even the table is in javascript .